# Why is every MediaPlayer object created null?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create an app that plays music, but am having some problems with the MediaPlayer class.

Every time I use `MediaPlayer.start()`, it returns the error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference`

I tried making an entirely new project with ONLY the MediaPlayer Code, but this error persists. Here is the code for reference:

```
package com.example.player;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.songa);

        player.start();


    }
}
```

songa is the name of a .mp3 file in the project's raw folder, as shown below:
[project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtnPd.png)

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` ?

Comment: Now it prints this error: https://imgur.com/a/fido5GC

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales No, you need to use the create factory method.

Comment: @BasilCosmopoulos `Every time I use MediaPlayer.start(), it returns the error:` you are using `MediaPlayer.start()` or `player.start()` to start your media?? because this code is correct and it definatly play your music proper.